# Regex get color value after color name

Tags: regex

I have this string `Red:255,Green:255,Blue:255`
**I am trying to get for example: the `255` value of red**.

I am very new to regex and I have tried `(?<=Red:\s).*(?=\s,)` but it does not work.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You have no spaces, why use `\s`? A quick fix will be `(?<=Red:).*?(?=,)`. Without any other details, the answer in the linked question is enough.

Comment: Regex might not be the best answer. Why not split(",") then split(":") ?

Answer (score 0):

For java you can use this regex:

```
Red:(\d+),Green:(\d+),Blue:(\d+)
```

You can try here: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex:

```
Red:(\d+),.*
```